# How to use the :last-child selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to simply add a `border-bottom` to the last `.slab`

I tried a few things and I am unable to understand what is going on.

**Case 1 - use `.wrapper:last-child`**

If I try this on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrGZEW) or on Stackoverflow snippets, I don't get a `border-bottom` on last `.slab`

If I try this on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kccqo7po/) or run the code separately in Chrome, I get a `border-bottom` on last `.slab`. However, if I uncomment `<div class="something">New</div>`, then the `border-bottom` on last `.slab` vanishes in both JSFiddle and on Chrome.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 10em;
    margin: 1em;
}
.wrapper:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
.slab {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
</div>
<!--<div class="something">New</div>-->
```

**Case 2 - use `.slab:last-child`**

Turns out this works everywhere - JSFiddle, Chrome, codepen.io and on Stackoverflow. But I thought the selection was really for the last-child ***of*** `.slab` and not the last `.slab`

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 10em;
    margin: 1em;
}
.slab {
    background-color: #eee;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 1em;
}
.slab:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
    <div class="slab">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Questions:

1. Does `.slab:last-child` mean the last child of `.slab` or the last occurrence of `.slab` ?
2. In **case 1**, why is the `border-bottom` vanishing after the introduction of an unrelated element `.something` ?
3. What is the best way to apply `border-bottom` to the last `.slab` ?

Comment: Probably the "names" are a little confusing, but this `.slab:last-child ` doesn't refer to the `.slab` children. It says `get .slab where .slab is the last child of its parent`.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. > Does `.slab:last-child` mean the last child of `.slab` or the last occurrence of `.slab` ?

   Neither. It matches an element that

   - has the "slab" class, and
   - is the last child of its parent.

   The last `.slab` within its parent may not necessarily be its last child. `.slab:last-child` will match if and only if both conditions are true for the given element.
2. > In **case 1**, why is the `border-bottom` vanishing after the introduction of an unrelated element `.something` ?

   Because then the last child of the parent of `.wrapper` becomes that other element. This element isn't unrelated to `.wrapper` — it's related to it by way of being its next sibling.

   The `.slab` elements within that wrapper *never* receive a border; the border is being applied to the `.wrapper` for as long as it is the last child of *its* parent. (Incidentally, the parent of `.wrapper` in your examples is implied to be `body`.)
3. > What is the best way to apply `border-bottom` to the last `.slab` ?

   You won't be able to do this reliably unless you can guarantee that the only possible children of `.wrapper` are `.slab` elements, in which case the class name then becomes quite irrelevant (but you can still include it in your selector so you avoid matching the last child of `.wrapper` when it's *not* a `.slab`).

Answer (score 2):

The `:last-child` [structural pseudo-class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) applies to siblings of a parent. It is equivalent to `:nth-last-child(1)`,

In terms of your code, you would apply `:last-child` to `.slab` to select the last sibling of parent `div.wrapper`.

If the last child of `div.wrapper` did not have a `slab` class, then the selector wouldn't match. It would do nothing.

If the `:last-child` were applied to the `div` children of `div.wrapper`, like this:

`.wrapper > div:last-child { ... }`

... then the selector would match the last child regardless of the `class`, `id` or other attributes. It would match any `div`. If the last child was not a `div`, the selector would do nothing.

If you wanted to match the last child of `div.wrapper`, regardless of *anything* – meaning it just needs to be the last child – then you could do something like this:

`.wrapper > *:last-child { ... }`

Without the `>` child combinator, let's say `.wrapper  *:last-child { ... }`, the last child of all descendant parent elements would be matched.

---

When you select `.wrapper:last-child`, you're targeting the element with class `wrapper` that is the last child of its parent (presumably `body`, in this case).

If `div.wrapper` is the only child of its parent, then `:last-child`, `:first-child`, `:only-child` and most other structural pseudo-class keyword selectors would match.

---

For a better understanding of these selectors (and all others), refer to this section of the CSS spec:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2):

`last-child` means exactly what is says...the very last **element** that is a child of a parent.

Not the last of class...the last element.

There is no `last-of-class` selector.

This: `.slab:last-child` means the last child that **also** has a class of `.slab`.

If it's not the last-child it won't apply and, equally, if it doesn't have a class of `.slab` it won't be selected.